# Mapping a route to a scope as a filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have a model called `Order` with the scopes

```
scope :paid, where("paid_at IS NOT NULL")
scope :outstanding, where("paid_at IS NULL")
```

Now I want my app to list all orders (both paid and outstanding) on myapp/orders and to list only the paid orders on <strike>myapp/paid</strike> myapp/orders/paid. The outstanding ones similar.

Is there any convenient way to do this? Can I still use the RESTful route `resources :orders`in my routes.rb? Is there any built in way to accomplish that?

EDIT: Path was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not a built in way to accomplish this structure.

However, a true RESTful artist would say,  you could create a Paid controller for use with the Index option, to show `@paid  = Order.paid`.

Now I personally will break the suggested RESTful design, to allow ONE extra get.  In this case I'd map the route order#paid to match 'paid' and just put in the Controller `@paid = Order.paid'` (probably want pagination, but your call).